# Javascript: loop through array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is driving me crazy. I'm just trying to print out an array and it's not working. What am I missing? The results variable is returning "undefined" which much mean my for loop isn't working correctly. Everything else works properly, the console.log I have correctly displays the fields are added to the array.

```js
// The list of accounts array.
var accountsArray = [];

function addAccount() {
  // Take fields and put user data into varables.
  var accountName = document.getElementById('accountName').value;
  var accountBalance = document.getElementById('accountBalance').value;
  var accountType = document.getElementById("accountType");
  var accountTypeSelected = accountType.options[accountType.selectedIndex].text;
  var accountCurrency = document.getElementById("accountCurrency");
  var accountCurrencySelected = accountCurrency.options[accountCurrency.selectedIndex].text;

  // Put these variables into the array.
  accountsArray.push(accountName);
  accountsArray.push(accountBalance);
  accountsArray.push(accountTypeSelected);
  accountsArray.push(accountCurrencySelected);

  // Items added to the array, logged.
  console.log('user added: ' + accountsArray);
}

function accountsListHtml() {

  var results;

  // Loop through the array
  for (var i = 0; i < accountsArray.length; i++) {
    results = accountsArray[i];
  }

  document.getElementById('accountsList').innerHTML = results;
}
```

Here's a link to all the files. It's an iOS web app using Framework7. [Balance Pro](http://jordankennedy.com/balancepro/index.html)

Comment: each assignment `results = accountsArray[i];` overwrites previous one

Comment: `addAccount()`, which populates the array, is never called, at least from the code you've posted.

Comment: @Utkanos It is called in the HTML 'onclick'

Comment: Where and when is `accountsListHtml()` called ? If it's before `addAccount()` result must be empty.

Comment: @MartinErnst Take a look at all the code [Balance Pro](http://www.jordankennedy.com/balancepro/index.html)

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0z9ed2z/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `accountsListHtml()` in `body.onload`. At that point `accountsArray` is empty.
I can't find any other possibility to call `accountsListHtml()` on that page you linked to.

Add one line inside function `addAccount()` and it will work:

```
function addAccount() {

    /* vour code */

    console.log('user added: ' + accountsArray);

    accountsListHtml(); // add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `results = accountsArray[i];` to `results += accountsArray[i];`.

**Update**
And initialize `results` with an empty string, for example :)

Comment: Still getting undefined.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: It's a little complicated for jsfiddle. Here's a link to my server where I uploaded the code. It is an iOS web app using Framework7. [link](http://www.jordankennedy.com/balancepro/index.html)

Comment: Don't really know what you expect - it's working fine (at least the way I see it) on Chrome 37. See [this screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16940002/myapp.png).

Answer (score 0):

`for (var i = 0; i < accountsArray.length; i++) {
        results = accountsArray[i];
    }`

The statement in the for loop i.e. `results = accountsArray[i];` overwrites the variable `results` evry loop run. You could change the statement to :

`results += accountsArray[i].toString();`

and initialise `results` to an empty string.

Comment: Hmm, just tried that and now it's just returning the empty string (results = ' ')

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/95ztrmk3/13/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="accountsList"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
// The list of accounts array.
var accountsArray = [];

addAccount();
accountsListHtml();

function addAccount() {
    // Take fields and put user data into varables.
    var accountName = "John Doe";
    var accountBalance = "500.00";
    var accountTypeSelected = "Checking"
    var accountCurrencySelected = "USD";

    // Put these variables into the array.
    accountsArray.push(accountName);
    accountsArray.push(accountBalance);
    accountsArray.push(accountTypeSelected);
    accountsArray.push(accountCurrencySelected);

    // Items added to the array, logged.
    console.log('user added: ' + accountsArray);
}

function accountsListHtml() {

    var results = [];

    // Loop through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < accountsArray.length; i++) {
        results += accountsArray[i] + " ";
    }

    document.getElementById('accountsList').innerHTML = results;
    console.log(results);

}
```

Assuming the input isn't malformed or otherwise weird.  I made sure Javascript recognizes `results` is an empty array and not a string or something: `var results = []`

Comment: I tried this on my end, and I'm still not sure why it isn't working. I just uploaded your edits to the code, [Balance Pro](http://www.jordankennedy.com/balancepro/index.html)

Comment: @jryankennedy I think the issue is probably related to the order in which your functions are being called, in that case.  It looks like `accountsListHtml` is invoked once, when the <body> loads and the form fields are empty (yielding zero results).  Either way, it looks like it wouldn't be an issue with looping through an array at this point.